# Shell script as default action for downloads in Firefox

Tags: linux, bash, firefox, shell

Is it possible to have a shell script as default download action in Firefox? In the manual (https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/change-firefox-behavior-when-open-file) only GUI programs are discussed.

I want zip files automatically passed to `unzip` , so they are automatically unextracted instead of having to choose extract options in my GUI program. The "Use other" option in Firefox only allows me to pass a program without any parameters. When I tried to use a shell script it didn't get executed at all, instead the file was saved to "Downloads" only.

I am running Firefox 64 on Linux.

Comment: Yes, you can use a shell script. Try a very simple script first that just echos into a /tmp file, make sure it is executable, and use the full pathname to it in the firefox setup.

Comment: I was under the impression I tried a simple script first, but after your suggestion I tried it again and it worked. I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It actually worked the second time. One has to make sure the script is executable. The script I used for automatically unpacking zip archives is:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/bash

filename=$(basename -- "$1")
filename="${filename%.*}"


unzip $1 -d "$HOME/Downloads/$filename/"
```

For extraction of filename without extension: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965053/extract-filename-and-extension-in-bash